# Using Pig searching on multiple columns

Tags: apache-pig

Hi i have tried to perform a search operation on my data using Apache pig. My code is like below

```
data = load 'sample.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray, fname:chararray, lname:chararray);
C = filter data by fname matches '.*Ma.*';
D = foreach C generate construction;
dump D;
```

Here i am able to find the data on either fname or lname. But i want to perform the search on both the columns.

I tried like below
1) applied the filter on data by adding the search condition on fname.

2) applied the filter on data by adding the search condition on lname

3) Union both the search result;

Is this the right way or any other good suggestions please.

Comment: Using OR condition in FILTER should help. Let us know if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR and perform the search in a single FILTER

```
C = filter data by fname matches '.*Ma.*' OR lname matches '.*Ma.*';
```